# use tor to run jar file in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: tor, jar

how to run jar file using tor or torsocks or torify in Ubuntu terminal ?

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
nohup torsocks java -jar tortest.jar &
```

also this one doesn't work :

```
nohup torify java -jar tortest.jar &
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @George my code won't start with a new ip, it starts with my previous ip address